# UV Map Distorts when I add bevel to model's edges

Tags: uv, bevel

This is driving me crazy. I am relatively new in Blender (2.8), but I've been working with 3D app (Houdini) a lot of years.
I am trying to model a simple cigarretes packs. I modeled it and UV it without issues, but when I added bevel to some edges, UV map going nuts and distorts:

[image]

The left one is the basic UV cube. Note the cut when box opens.
I've tried everything that I've found in forums: Inset faces, adding loopcuts, subdividing faces, separates every faces of the model, adding seams in all edges, and nothing. Distortion appears anyways.

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to unwrap again, at least the part that you've bevelled, once you've bevelled it has changed the UV mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the topology of your object with the bevel, it changes its UV. I don't know how it works with Houdini but in Blender you need to make sure that the seams are still ok, unwrap again, and align again with the image texture in the UV editor.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your responses, they will certainly works.
Reading more about Blender's UV toolset, I've found an alternative solution that seems to works fine too:

1- This is how UV looks after the bevel operation:
[image]

2- I selected bevel's faces and apply "follow active quads" (u key/follow active quads command):
[image]

3- The result is a nicely aligned set of UV quads:
[image]

Thank you guys, you centainly motivate me to go deeper.
Regards.